# renderIcon is not a function when using react-navigation v5

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I want to add custom icons in my bottom tab navigator. However, whenever I try to use tabBarIcon, I have this error: renderIcon is not a function (in TabBarIcon.tsx line 40). Any ideas how I can resolve this error?

Here are my dependencies:

```
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.8.0",
    "@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs": "^5.2.16",
    "@react-navigation/material-top-tabs": "^5.2.16",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.7.3",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.9.0",
    "expo": "~38.0.8",
    "expo-status-bar": "^1.0.2",
    "react": "~16.11.0",
    "react-dom": "~16.11.0",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-38.0.2.tar.gz",
```

And below is my code to make it:

```js
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

const TabBarIcon = (img_src) => {
  return (
    <Image
      style={{
        width: 22,
        height: 26.4,
      }}
      source={img_src}
    />
  );
};

const BottomTabNavigator = () => {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator initialRouteName="MyNotes">
      <Tab.Screen
        name="MyNotes"
        component={MyNotes}
        options={{
          tabBarLabel: "Notes",
          tabBarIcon: TabBarIcon("../assets/notes.png"),
        }}
      />
      <Tab.Screen name="Feed" component={Feed} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Discover" component={Discover} />
      <Tab.Screen name="MyProfile" component={MyProfile} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
};

export default BottomTabNavigator;
```

I also tried to replace TabBarIcon("../assets/notes.png") by  but had the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

render tabBarIcon like this..

import asset icons

```
import home_icon from './assets/images/home-icon.png';
import notification_icon from './assets/images/notification-icon.png';
import favourites_icon from './assets/images/favourites-icon.png';
```

for tabBarActive and inActive color

```
const tabActiveColor = '#030303';
const tabInActiveColor = '#666666';
```

rest of the tab implementation would be like this.

```
<Tab.Navigator
        screenOptions={({ route }) => ({
          tabBarIcon: ({ focused, color, size }) => {
            let tabIcon = home_icon

if (route.name === 'Home') {
              tabIcon = home_icon;
            } else if (route.name === 'Notification') {
              tabIcon = notification_icon;
            } else if (route.name === 'Favourite') {
              tabIcon = favourites_icon;
            } 
            // You can return any component that you like here!
            return (
              <Image
                source={tabIcon}
                resizeMode='contain'
                style={{
                  height: 30,
                  width: 30,
                  tintColor: focused ? tabActiveColor : tabInActiveColor,
                }}
              />
            );
          },
        })}
        tabBarOptions={{
          showLabel: false,
          style: { zIndex: 110 },
          safeAreaInset: { bottom: 'never' },
        }}
      >
        <Tab.Screen
          name='Home'
          component={this.HomeStackScreen}
          options={({ route }) => ({
            tabBarVisible: this.getTabBarVisible(route),
          })}
        />
<Tab.Screen name='Notification' component={NotificationModule} />

        <Tab.Screen name='Favourite' component={FavouriteModule} />
        
      </Tab.Navigator>
```

Comment: Can you show me how you would put a different logo for each Tab.Screen ?

Comment: I now have the following error: Cant find tabActiveColor

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I now have a last little issue. As the initial Route is MyNotes, the cursor is not defined as selected when I land in MyNotes. Is there a way to fix it ? Except that, it's working !

Comment: Ok but if you know an easy way to add this, your code would be more complete. Thanks